# Can I read all the connection strings from web.config without the names of each one? ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, web-config, connection-string

I want to read all the connection strings from web.config programmatically without specifying the names of the connection strings. And use that information for different purposes e.g. print out on the screen. Is it possible and how can I do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You obviously did not try anything. This would do it

```
  foreach (var s in System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
  {
        Response.Write(s);
  }
```

Where `ConnectionStrings` is a collection of `ConnectionStringSettings`

```
foreach (System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings s in System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
{
     Response.Write(s);
}
```